# Subclassing native objects: instanceof not working properly

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to subclass the native JS `Error` object in CoffeeScript to get specialized error types, but i found that the `instanceof` does not work correctly if i don't define a constructor in the subclasses:

```
class SimpleError extends Error
class EmptyConstructorError extends Error
  constructor: ->
class SuperConstructorError extends Error
  constructor: -> 
    super

new SimpleError instanceof SimpleError                     # -> false
new EmptyConstructorError instanceof EmptyConstructorError # -> true
new SuperConstructorError instanceof SuperConstructorError # -> true
```

The problem seems to be caused by how the [generated JS](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#try:class%20SimpleError%20extends%20Error%0Aclass%20EmptyConstructorError%20extends%20Error%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20-%3E%0Aclass%20SuperConstructorError%20extends%20Error%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20-%3E%20super%0A%0Aconsole.log%20new%20SimpleError%20instanceof%20SimpleError%0Aconsole.log%20new%20EmptyConstructorError%20instanceof%20EmptyConstructorError%0Aconsole.log%20new%20SuperConstructorError%20instanceof%20SuperConstructorError%0A) constructor functions are defined. When i *don't* define a constructor in CoffeeScript:

```
SimpleError = (function(_super) {

  __extends(SimpleError, _super);

  function SimpleError() {
    return SimpleError.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  return SimpleError;

})(Error);
```

And when i *do* define a constructor in CoffeeScript:

```
SuperConstructorError = (function(_super) {

  __extends(SuperConstructorError, _super);

  function SuperConstructorError() {
    SuperConstructorError.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  return SuperConstructorError;

})(Error);
```

As you can see, the difference is a simple `return` in the first case. I don't understand why this makes any difference in the `instanceof` behavior though, as the super constructor is just being applied to the `this` object (i.e. the super constructor is not being called with `new`), but then again i don't understand a whole lot of how JS constructors work =P

And the weird thing is that this behavior seems to only happen when subclassing native JS objects. If i subclass CoffeeScript classes everything works as expected.

Any idea of why this might be happening and how could i avoid writing dummy constructors just for the `instanceof` operator to work correctly?

Thanks!

### Update

So the user matyr [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10807905/581845) with a link to the commit where this behavior was introduced, but it doesn't quite explain what is happening here, so i'll try to explain that a little bit in case anyone else wonders why this works this way.

The main problem is this inherited nasty "feature" from JavaScript which let us define a constructor function that returns an object other than the one being constructed:

```
function Foo() {
    return {'LOL': 'You fool!'};
}
new Foo() instanceof Foo // -> false
```

And there is also the fact that some native constructors, like `Error`, `Array`, `String` and whatnot don't need to be called with `new`: they will just return a new object of the corresponding type if you happen to forget it.

In the end, add these two ugly things together and the result is that you should remember to write `class MyError extends Error then constructor: -> super` instead of the more intuitive `class MyError extends Error` if you want the `instanceof` operator to work properly with `MyError`. That's because CoffeeScript's implicit constructor will just return whatever the parent constructor returns, and in this case will do `return Error.apply(this, arguments)` which will just return a shinny new error object instead of the object you passed as the `this` argument. Yay!

### Update 2 (Feb 25 2013)

This problem [was fixed in CoffeeScript 1.5.0](http://coffeescript.org/#changelog)! =D

Now extending native objects works as expected:

```
class MyError extends Error
new MyError instanceof MyError # -> true :)
```

### Update 3 (Mar 04 2013)

Aaand it's gone on 1.6.0 =P

Comment: Oddly enough, your code from the first block works for me in Chrome, Canary, Safari and Firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/WpkgS/ Did I miss something?

Comment: By works, I mean they all return true as expected.

Comment: @Sandro That's weird :S. It also works for me in that link, but the strange thing is that jsfiddle generated code seems to be different to what Try CoffeeScript generates. Take a look at [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WpkgS/1/) with the developer tools enabled to see the code and then [what Try CoffeeScript generates](http://goo.gl/eRJkX). Now this became more confusing :S

Comment: My initial guess is that JSFiddle is using an older version of CoffeeScript and the latest version breaks this functionality. This updated JSFiddle which also uses the latest CoffeeScript JS file breaks as well. http://jsfiddle.net/WpkgS/2/

Comment: The CoffeeScript changelog indicates some changes to how `super` works so that might be related. It might be easier if you head over to irc.freenode.net #coffeescript and mention this there maybe?

Comment: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#changelog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For better or worse, the `return` was [added](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/commit/080ed2e8dd98bba1bff85dd413fa11f1d4014e92) on 1.3.1 to fix [#1966](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1966) (and [#2111](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2111)).

Comment: Thanks for the links! I think i understand the motivation for this change now. But i think it's kind of unfortunate that these JS nastiness leaks through CS. I'd really expect that if `class MyError extends Error` then `new MyError instanceof MyError`. Having to define it as `class MyError extends Error then constructor: -> super` seems quite out of place. And i really don't know why someone would like/need to return a different object from a constructor in JS or in CS :S (i.e. i don't understand the need to implement in CS what those two issues request :S).

Comment: If you are interested, i opened an issue/discussion about this in [jashkenas/coffee-script](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2359) :D