# Custom Error not propagated properly on throw statement or next() call

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mongoose

I'm developing a Node.js/CoffeeScript app where I'm using a class hierarchy for errors. Everything works great when I'm using `throw` statements in the root of a route handler:

```
class APIError extends Error
    constructor: ->

app.error (err, req, res, next) ->
    if err instance of APIError
       console.log 'APIError captured'

app.get '/', (req, res, next) ->
    throw new APIError
```

However, with Mongoose, using `throw` statement in a callback function:

```
app.get '/', (req, res, next) ->
    UserModel.where('name', 'Joe').findOne (err, doc) ->
        throw new APIError
```

results in

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:413
    throw err;
          ^
Error:
```

When I call `next()` instead, as in

```
app.get '/', (req, res, next) ->
    UserModel.where('name', 'Joe').findOne (err, doc) ->
        return next new APIError
```

or even use it in the main body of a handler:

```
app.get '/', (req, res, next) ->
    next new APIError
```

I get `undefined` being printed out in the console.

Changing the last statement to `return next Error` works as expected, i.e. an exception stack trace is being printed out in the console:

```
app.get '/', (req, res, next) ->
    return next Error 'This works as expected'
```

Is it Node.js issue or the way I'm defining classes in CoffeeScript? Any ideas how to make such error hierarchy to work?

### Update 1

I can confirm that it's the way CoffeeScript's classes are implemented. Using standard JS prototype chain definitions solves the problem, but it does not feel right.

Comment: This one looks to be somehow related: [Subclassing native objects: instanceof not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805084/subclassing-native-objects-instanceof-not-working-properly?rq=1)

Comment: Yeah it definitely is - I was struggling with something similar the other day, where extending Error with a new custom error wasn't being thrown properly, or wouldn't actually be of the correct type, depending on the constructor - something isn't quite right with the way it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `name` attribute of the class in its constructor solves the problem (line no. 3):

```
class APIError extends Error
    constructor: ->
        @name = 'APIError'

app.use (err, req, res, next) ->
    if err instance of APIError
        console.log 'Error captured'

app.get '/', (req, res, next) ->
    #This will work: captured by error handler
    throw new APIError

app.get '/in-mongoose-callback', (req, res, next) ->
    UserModel.where('name', 'Joe').findOne (err, doc) ->
        #This one works as expected: captured by error handler
        return next new APIError
```

This is due to [one of the changes](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2052) that landed in CoffeeScript 1.3.3 (MAY 15, 2012):

> Due to the new semantics of JavaScript's strict mode, CoffeeScript no longer guarantees that constructor functions have names in all runtimes. See #2052 for discussion.

Note that using `throw` statement instead of `next()` inside a Mongoose query callback **will not work**.

Answer (score 1):

While using express, I extend Error, set the name as prototype property, and perform a stack trace.

```
class RequestError extends Error
    name: 'RequestError'
    constructor:(@status, message)->
        super message
        Error.captureStackTrace @, @constructor
```

I can do `new RequestError 403, 'Invalid username/password.'` for a bad user signin, or `new RequestError 404, 'Page not found.'` for a bad page request.  When I catch the error I do

```
require 'colors'
console.error error.stack.red  # logs where any error occured
if error instanceof RequestError
    # proper response for user errors
    response.status(error.status).send(error.message)
else response.status(500).send('Internal Server Error') # for 'other' errors the user only gets back a 500 'Internal Server Error'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell but we had issues on errors until we moved them to the end of the server script, even after the start server.  This is using Express with Node, but could give you a hint.  Before we had this near the beginning of server file assuming no issues but started working after we moved all our error handling to end.  Unsure if router or middleware of framework order of operations issue but seemed to fix our issues.

---

```
/////////////////////////////
// Start Server
/////////////////////////////

app.listen(siteConf.port);

//////////////////////////
// Error Handling
//////////////////////////  
function NotFoundError(req, message){
    this.name = "NotFoundError";
    this.status = 404;
    this.message = message || (req.method + " " + req.url + " could not be found");
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, NotFoundError);
}
NotFoundError.prototype.__proto__ = Error.prototype;

function ProtectedResourceError(req, message){
    this.name = "ProtectedResourceError";
    this.status = 401;
    this.message = message || (req.url + " is protected");
}
ProtectedResourceError.prototype.__proto__ = Error.prototype;

function ValidationError(req, message, errors){
    this.name = "ValidationError";
    this.status = 400;
    this.message = message || ("Error when validating input for " + req.url);
    this.errors = errors;
}
ValidationError.prototype.__proto__ = Error.prototype;

function SearchError(req, message){
    this.name = "SearchError";
    this.status = 400;
    this.message = message || ("Error when searching");
}
SearchError.prototype.__proto__ = Error.prototype;

// If no route matches, throw NotFoundError
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("No matching route for " + req.url);
    next(new NotFoundError(req));        
});

// General error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    //console.log("Trapped error : " + err);

    // handle exceptions
    if (err instanceof ValidationError) {
        standardResponse(req, res, {error: err.message, fields: err.errors}, err.status, err.message);
    } else if (err instanceof ProtectedResourceError) {
        standardResponse(req, res, {error: err.message}, err.status, err.message);
    } else if (err instanceof NotFoundError) {
        standardResponse(req, res, {error: err.message}, err.status, err.message);
    } else if (err instanceof SearchError) {
        standardResponse(req, res, {error: err.message}, err.status, err.message);
    } else {
        standardResponse(req, res, {error: err.message}, 500, err.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: I can confirm that defining class hierarchy using JS prototype chain makes `throw new APIError` work in Mongoose query callbacks, but not the `next new APIError` call.

Comment: instead of declaring "new" have you tried just 'next APIError' ?  I'm unsure difference with Coffee Script vs V8 syntax.  With ours we declare within parens:  if (err) return next(new Error('Could not retrieve xxx'));

Comment: CoffeeScript _does_ define class hierarchy using the JS [[Proto]] chain. However, this code also calls `Error.captureStackTrace` which you should probably do too. Also, calling `super` in your constructor might help.