# Property in subclass of Error not set

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I have a Coffeescript subclass of `Error`. The following CoffeeScript script

```
class MyError extends Error
  constructor: (message, @cause) ->
    super message

myError = new MyError 'This is the error message!'

console.log myError instanceof MyError
console.log myError instanceof Error
console.log "'#{myError.message}'"
console.log myError.message == ''
```

displays

```
true
true
''
true
```

under Node.js v0.10.20.

Why is the message property of `myError` empty?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10807905/1961149 which points to issues https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2111 and https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1966

The problem is with the return value of the Error constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen these links before I posted this question. After reading all these issues and comments, and after trying the `instanceof` examples (which are all running ok, as far as I see), I thought that there is no issue left with subclassing.

Comment: Knowing that `util.isError(myError)` returns `false` under Node.js, the answer to my question is ["An argument against subclassing `Error`"](http://bjb.io/development/2012/05/06/an-argument-against-subclassing-error.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly setting the `@message` works

```
class MyError extends Error
  constructor: (@message,@cause)->
    Error.captureStackTrace(@,@)

coffee> ee=new MyError 'test'
{ message: 'test', cause: undefined }
coffee> "#{ee}"
'Error: test'
coffee> ee.message
'test'
coffee> ee instanceof MyError
true
coffee> ee instanceof Error
true
coffee> throw new MyError 'test'
Error: test
    at new MyError (repl:10:11)
...
```

`super` does fine when another class builds on `MyError`

```
class OError extends MyError
   constructor: (msg)->
     super msg
     @name='OError'
```

The following displays the right message, and is true for `util.isError`, is `instanceof Error`, but not `instanceof Error1`.  So it is a specialized constructor of an `Error`, rather than a 'subclass'.

```
class Error1 extends Error
   constructor: (@message)->
     self = super
     self.name = 'Error1'
     return self
```

This is for `node: '0.10.1', 'coffee-script': '1.6.3'`

The last example in the `bjb.io` article is (in Coffeescript):

```
CustomError = (msg)->
  self = new Error msg
  self.name = 'CustomError'
  self.__proto__ = CustomError.prototype
  return self
CustomError.prototype.__proto__= Error.prototype
# CustomError::__proto__= Error::  # I think
```

That satisfies all the tests, `util.isError`, `instanceof Error`, `instanceof CustomError`, `"#{new CustomError 'xxx'}"`.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. It confirmed my conclusion that subclassing `Error` in CS does not lead to a class which fullfills all my requirements: correct `instanceof`, correct properties **and** `util.isError ee == true` under Node.js. Having read "[An argument against subclassing `Error`](http://bjb.io/development/2012/05/06/an-argument-against-subclassing-error.html)" I dont think of subclassing `Error` anymore.

Comment: Thx for the addition! My question is now answered more than completely! As far as I understand, `CustomError` satisfies all the tests but is not a real subclass. I checked that `class CustomError2 extends CustomError ...` does not satisfy all the tests.